# Can I use live USB to format HD and install Ubuntu with it?

Tags: installation, boot, usb, live-usb, format

I've tried to install Ubuntu on my computer and now can't even turn it on.

The problem is that the computer CD-ROM is not working so I was trying to get it on a USB somehow.

The computer is old and slow and was running Windows XP; 750 RAM, 2.4GB, 40GB HDD. Could that be a problem for Ubuntu?

I tried to attached two pictures, first after BIOS noise and second (and last thing I see) but I can't.

Any idea what can I do? I don't want to use Windows.
Is there a way to format HDD from USB and install Ubuntu also from USB?

Comment: You can upload screenshots to an image hosting site such as [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and post the link here.

Answer (score 1):

Really if your computer is not booting up and the BIOS is playing sounds on the system speaker then it isn't an Ubuntu issue. It probably is a hardware based issue.

Comment: I cant post pictures unfortunately but when I tried to run Live Linux from my usb I got message: cant boot. Now Im downloading Ubuntu and I will try to use Universal USB Installer. But back to my question, can I format my HDD with USB ??

Comment: Yes you can. Follow the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: Still Boot Error. Could it be that my old motherboard is not supporting USB booting ?

Comment: Have a look at the support section of the website of your motherboard manufacturer for the answer to that.

Comment: Naah I think its just too old computer... I cant boot it up. Im getting message "hardware monitor found an error", then need to press f1 to continue and then Im getting all screen of stuff.          PCI device listing and some tables. Flashing cursor and cant do anything - can only turn it off. Was hoping I could format from usb and install linux but tried with few different techniques live linux, unetbooting etc and no luck. I give up, computer goes to the bin tomorrow...  thx for help !

Comment: Maybe try removing and reinstalling the memory sticks and graphics card first then rebooting - if still no luck, then into the bin it goes.

Comment: Did you try to boot from the usb you created on another pc to be sure that the usb drive is bootable?

Answer (score 0):

With your hardware, according to the official [Ubuntu hardware requirements for 12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/minimum-hardware-reqts.html) you shouldn't have any issue with it as the recommended requirements are:

- 512 Megabytes of RAM
- 5 Gigabytes of Hard-Drive space

I'd assume there's unfortunately something wrong with your hardware, as your laptop hardware meets these specifications. I'd say try seeing if you can correctly change the boot order, maybe try an older (more-lightweight) Ubuntu distro just to check, but otherwise I'm afraid there's not much to be done.